# Scrolling column that stops scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I really like how [Vice](http://www.vice.com/en_uk)'s second column (see on the homepage) scrolls with the rest of the content, like a regular column, then when you reach the bottom of that column, it stops scrolling whereas the rest of the content continues scrolling as normal.

I've had a quick look at the code but it's not obvious, what's the technique used to achieve this? Is it something that can be retrofitted to an existing site?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain how its works.

First the column works like a regular column. Example css:

```
#regular
{
width:200px;
height:500px;
background:gray;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
```

Vice uses jQuery to check if your scroll position is greater than the position of the column. If this is true then the css is changed to something like this:

```
position: fixed;
top:200px; //menu height
```

Or

```
position: absolute
top: scroll.offset height.
```

And then the column scrolls together with the screen.

How to dynamically change the css?
Example code:

```
var windowScreen = $(window);
var column = $("#regular");

//Call function if user scrolls
windowScreen.scroll(function() {

   if(windowScreen.scrollTop() == 200)
   {
       $("#regular").css({"position":"fixed", "top":"200px"});
   }

}
```

Comment: This solution worked a treat, one thing that I needed to be aware of, however, was that the container explicitly needed `position: relative;` setting on it for the fixed positioning to work as expected. Also, the fixed positioned element is best moved around with margin.